# Amazon SES Complaint Notifications not Received in SNS complaint topic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, amazon-sns

I'm not receiving complaint notifications published into my SNS complaint topic, when i *Report Spam* in Gmail or Yahoo mail inbox. But, I am able to generate complaint notifications by  using Amazon mailbox simulator. It perfectly works. Do i need to make some configurations to receive complaint notifications from Gmail / Yahoo mailboxes?The mail sending client subscribes using Http endpoint.  Please note that all other notifications (Hard Bounces,Soft bounces, Delivered) are successfully received. I'm not running the email program in ec2 instance. It runs in my local machine and exposed to the internet using ngrok.

Note : I did run through other related questions in SO. But,they didn't help to resolve my case.

Comment: Do you see the subscriptions in question in the SNS console? Can you verify your mail sending client is actually receiving nothing (vs receiving something and not handling the notification properly)?

Comment: @Chris There is actually nothing received by the client.

Comment: I have encountered the same problem. I have added the mail id in spam and blocked it to get the complaint object. And sent the mail to that user from blocked mail id. Though I am getting that notification as 'Delivery' instead of a complaint.

Comment: Have you found solution for this, I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Hey, I'm having the same problem. Guys, does anyone have a solution for this? I have production access and getting all notification just complaint is missing.